# How can I get multiple instances of string from multi line string output

Tags: java, string, selenium, pattern-matching, substring

My output string is in this multiline format. I need to get  the dates which is between "Detection Date:" and "Confidence  ". There are multiple instances and the lines in which they occur are not constant.

```
abcd efg hijk
xxxxx: yyyyy
zzzz:aaaa
bbbb
ccc
Detection Date:
**01/20/2015**
Confidence:
mmmm:nnnn
oooo
abcd 
xxxxx: yyyyy
ccc
Detection Date:
**01/25/2015**
Confidence:
mmmm:nnnn
oooo
ppppp
qqqq:
rrrr
```

I tried the following. I converted the multiline output to single line(I thought it would help) but of no avail

```
for (int i = 3; i < getDates.size()-47; i++) {
            String strDateFrmRslt = getDates.get(i).getText();
            System.out.println("The LENGTH of the text is  "+ strDateFrmRslt.length());
            strDateFrmRslt=strDateFrmRslt.replaceAll("[\r\n]+", " ");

            Pattern p = Pattern.compile(" Detection Date:([^>]*) ");                
            Matcher m = p.matcher(strDateFrmRslt);


            while (m.find()) {

                  System.out.println(m.group());
                }

        }
```

This is the output I get. It gets to the beginning of the first instance of Detection Date and grabs everything after that. I ONLY need "01/20/2015 ' and '01/25/2015'

```
The LENGTH of the text is  763
Detection Date: 01/20/2015 Confidence:  mmmm:nnnn oooo abcd  xxxxx: yyyyy ccc Detection Date: 01/25/2015 Confidence:
```

Thanks for checking...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look at [this](https://regex101.com/r/rA7iT6/2) example and implement the Java equivalent by using the `Pattern.DOTALL | Pattern.MULTILINE` flags to denote the `ms` flags in the example I provided.

This should make your `while(m.find()` loop work.

Alternatively, if you know that your markers will be on a line by themselves, you could simply look for them and use boolean flags. It might take you longer to write, but I think that the end result will be clearer.

Comment: Wow.. nice link... The ** are my formatting so I used "Detection Date:.*?(.+?).*?Confidence:"      and got my date in four lines 
Detection Date: 1/21/2015 1:25:08 AM Confidence:
Detection Date: 1/20/2015 11:59:59 PM Confidence:
Detection Date: 1/20/2015 11:59:59 PM Confidence:                             I guess I will have to use substring to trim the beginning and end characters

Comment: @user3749141: With the regex I provided, you can use `m.group(1)` to get the date.

Answer (score 0):

Brute force method but can you not do this:

```
String[] stringParts = inputString.split("\\r?\\n");
ArrayList<String> foundDates = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 0; i<stringParts.length; i++) {
if (stringParts[i].equals("Detection Date") && stringParts[i + 2].equals("Confidence")) {
    foundDates.add(stringParts[i + 1]);
    }
}
```

Assuming you can parse the multi-line string with line breaks, you are adding all the strings that follow Detection Date to a List.

Comment: What about Confidence:? The text must be found between "Detection Date" and "Confidence:"

Comment: The only question remains whether the inputString is coming from a file. If it is, we should just be dumping each line into a list instead of splitting ;)

Comment: Thanks for the post but I used another answer and it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that:

```
    strDateFrmRslt  = strDateFrmRslt .replaceAll("[\r\n]+", "");
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("Detection Date:\\*\\*(\\d\\d/\\d\\d/\\d\\d\\d\\d)\\*\\*Confidence");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(strDateFrmRslt);
    while(matcher.find())
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
```

Comment: Look at the size of that pattern. ;)